# SQL Server Service cannot be started

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, event-log

I have been trying to install and start SQL Server 2012. I succeeded installing SQL Server 2012 Management Studio but I am still working to start its service.

When I tried to start it I got an error

> The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion

I looked at ERRORLOG file and there are 4 type of errors in it.

> Error: 17190, Severity: 16, State: 1.
> Initializing the FallBack certificate failed with error code: 1, state: 20, error number: 0.
>
> Error: 17182, Severity: 16, State: 1.
> TDSSNIClient initialization failed with error 0x80092004, status code 0x80. Reason: Unable to initialize SSL support.
>
> Error: 17826, Severity: 18, State: 3.
> Could not start the network library because of an internal error in the network library. To determine the cause, review the errors immediately preceding this one in the error log.
>
> Error: 17120, Severity: 16, State: 1.
> SQL Server could not spawn FRunCommunicationsManager thread. Check the SQL Server error log and the Windows event logs for information about possible related problems.

I googled and found out a lot of solutions but any of them didn't work. What are the reason of this problems? How can I solve these? How can I restart my service without any problem?

Thanks for your answers...

**EDIT**: I solved the problem changing properties of service. I changed log-on settings as **Built-In Local System** However I can't log-in to SQL Server Management Studio with both Windows Auth. and SQL Server Auth.

My next question is why can't I log in?

Answer (score 2):

First check SQL Server log file. This can be a network issue. If that's it, it caused due to VIA protocol. Check SQL Server configuration manager and look for the Protocols enabled for that instance of SQL Server. Disable it.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) with the SQL Server Engine. SSMS is a tool for manipulating the objects in the engine - think of it as a very powerful, convenient, client. The engine (instance) is what you set a user that is the account used to start the engine.

When you installed SQL Server you assigned a user to be the SQL Server System Administrator. That is the user you need to login with. Once you login you can create additional logins (with less permissions) and assign these new logins as users to the various databases in the instance.

Answer (score 0):

I Used de Repair option on the installer, and work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and checking Event Viewer it suggests to check error log so I launched SSMS and despite the service being down, I actually managed to login to the instance and looked the error log which in my case was the login related.